# c# iText7 how to set the position of the top left corner of a paragraph

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, itext7

I wan't write a paragraph in the pdf file so that the top left corner of the paragraph is exactly positioned at the top left corner of the page 100,100.The code:

```
var targetPdfPath = "100x100.pdf";
using (PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(targetPdfPath)))
{
    Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);
    var page = pdfDoc.AddNewPage(PageSize.A4);
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Must be at (100,100)");
    PdfFont FontHELVETICA = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA);
    paragraph.SetFontSize(20f);
    var pageHeight = PageSize.A4.GetHeight();
    PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
    var rectHeight = 200f;
    var rectWidth = 200f;
    pdfCanvas.SetLineWidth(0.5f);
    pdfCanvas.Rectangle(100, pageHeight - 100 - rectHeight, 200, 200);//It is easy to place the rectangle in the position of (100,100)pt
    pdfCanvas.Stroke();

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, PageSize.A4);
    var paragraphHeight = 0f;//How to get it??
    paragraph.SetFixedPosition(100, pageHeight - 100f - paragraphHeight, 200);//It is difficult to place paragraphs in the position of (100,100)pt
    canvas.Add(paragraph);
}
```

I can't get the right result no matter how much I test.How can I do?
[100x100.pdf](https://docdro.id/z14dIWs)
[image]

Comment: In which way is the result of your code not as expected?

Comment: if you want it as (100,100), why is it written in the code (100, pageHeight - 100) ?

Comment: The origin is in the upper left corner.@Pac0

Comment: [100x100.pdf]https://docdro.id/UwUy0gO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already use a `Canvas`. How about setting the `Canvas` area to have its upper left corner at (100, 100) and let iText do the layout work:

```csharp
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, PageSize.A4.ApplyMargins(100, 0, 0, 100, false));
canvas.Add(paragraph);
```

You may have to set the paragraph margin and padding to 0 before adding:

```
paragraph.SetMarginTop(0);
paragraph.SetPaddingTop(0);
```

*([PositionParagraph](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext8/blob/master/src/test/csharp/content/PositionParagraph.cs#L23) test `PositionParagraphAt100_100`)*

(I don't have Adobe Illustrator, so I cannot check whether this conforms to Illustrator's idea of the top left corner of the text.)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the paragraph is not placed at (100100), but the Border is
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the objects why this may be a problem in interpretation.

**Required M at 20 Point font given is**
`paragraph.SetFixedPosition(98.6, pageHeight -114.6f, 200);`

[image]

You can see that the Text is placed at `100 750.85` exactly as a PDF will apply units so the page is 842 at the top and the text needs to be at 742 (8.85 units lower)

Let's try there, and yes we can now see it's better.

So 2 corrections are needed the letters need to be moved down by their msize and the M size needs to be a font where one M is an em wide.

[image]

So what works for an answer? Well it's roughly `98.6 727.4` (-114.6).

[image]